# inline functions within an inline function

Tags: c++, inline

for the following function:

```
inline void A() {
   ...
   B();
   ...
}
```

is *B* also inlined by the compiler?

If not, should I make *B* inline to increase performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the inline keywords will only cause the A code to be inlined inside the caller code. This will not affect inlining of B.

Besides this, in c++, the inline keyword is only a hint to the compiler, which is allowed to ignore it. Modern compilers decide when the functions need to be inlined, even if the keyword is not used.

Answer (score 6):

In most situations, you can rest comfortably leaving inlining-decisions to the compiler, which will know far better than you when and when not it will result in better performance.

In this specific situation, I would stronlgy suspect that it is completely up to the compiler what to do.

Comment: Also, the inline keyword is only a hint or a wish, the compiler is not required to follow it. I would bet that modern compilers simply ignore it.

Comment: Depends on the language. [C99's `inline` is not a hint at all.](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/myth-and-reality-about-inline-in-c99/).

Answer (score 4):

Somehow all the commenters failed to mention that there are cases when inline is NOT a mere hint to the compiler, but a mandated keyword. It happens when one puts a non-template definition of a function in the header file included by multiple .cpp files. In this case absence of inline will trigger a linker error. As a matter of fact, this is the only case when one should even bother typing those 6 characters. In other cases, compilers will inline everything they can - regardless of this keyword presence.

Comment: in the case you mentioned, is the function actually inlined or `inline` just resolve the linker error?

Comment: @MonsterHunter, it is guranteed to resolve a linker error. It does not guaratee to perform the actual inlining. But don't you worry. Modern compilers LOVE inlining. If anything can be inlined, it would be inlined :)

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a function/method `inline`, it is just a *hint* to the compiler that this particular function should be inlined. The compiler then may or may not inline it. The same applies for nested calls like the call to `B()` inside `A()`.

I would probably add `inline` specifier to both of the functions, but that's just a matter of style - modern optimizing compiler like GCC will optimize it anyways.